# Wave in expanding medium

Tags: waves

How is the behaviour of a wave modelled in a medium that is expanding faster than the wave is propagating within it?

I ask obviously because of the applicability of the question to the concept of an expanding universe.

Also, if energy cannot be created or destroyed but only transferred, and if energy has been lost from a part of the system in the emission of the wave, where is (or what is the nature of) the double-entry for the part of the system that gains energy, once all further parts of the system become unreachable for the wave due to the expansion of its medium?

Comment: Sounds interesting...  @Steve I have experienced downvotes without explanations too... feels really bad, but I guess you just have to get used to it.  Personally I think it is rather interesting

Comment: If the medium itself isn't interacting (and ignoring curved spacetime), wouldn't the only thing be a perceived stretching of wavelength? That would actually be why we believe the universe is expanding to my knowledge. I kind of wonder if the amplitude would have to decrease though.

Comment: @danielunderwood, that's sort of my question, that what happens when the wavelength is stretching at a rate such that it's trailing edge is not actually approaching it's leading edge anymore, and it's leading edge is not approaching any reachable object anymore? Also, "curved" or stretched spacetime is precisely the thing I don't want to be ignored, since that *is* the electromagnetic medium in this case.

Answer (score -1):

As the wave is moving, it loses energy due to various forces like friction acting on it.  Hence, the wave will come to a stop in the end.

> Also, if energy cannot be created or destroyed but only transferred, and if energy has been lost from a part of the system in the emission of the wave, where is (or what is the nature of) the double-entry for the part of the system that gains energy, once all further parts of the system become unreachable for the wave due to the expansion of its medium?

The double-entry part of the system will be at the end of the wave, since the wave will ultimately stop moving with the ever-expanding medium, since the wave cannot go on forever.

Comment: Seems ok... perhaps you could elaborate more?

Comment: Does this imply that electromagnetic waves, whilst apparently having a constant speed of propagation in space, do not have a constant lifetime? How is the energy then retained by, or returned to, the system when the wave expires? Or does it re-condense into a stationary particle? In other words, that the radiation of light into outer space, eventually converts to an elementary particle with mass at some distant point?

Comment: Yes, that is it....